# Generate CKRecord classes with properties like CoreData

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I'm migrating an app from CoreData to CloudKit. I hate using string-based key-value coding, because it prevents autocomplete and makes refactoring harder. With CoreData, we can have classes with properties automatically generated so that changes in the data model are automatically reflected in the generated classes and their properties. Is a similar process available for CloudKit?

Comment: No, there is not a similar process for CloudKit. You would have to write your own class to do so.

Comment: Thanks @maddy. I have actually been working on my own class structure for this, which at least means I can set and access the values using properties rather than KVC. CloudKit seems amazing from the point of view of how little code is required to use it (compared to the mess that was CoreData), but having to use KVC feels like a step back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` in iOS 13 bridges CoreData and CloudKit. This means local storage remains in CoreData and can use CoreData auto-generated classes and properties for accessing values. `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` handles the interface with CloudKit so no KVC is required.